# Difference between Hadoop completed and retired jobs

Tags: hadoop, jobs

The title makes the question pretty clear. Why are there two different sections in the jobtracker for completed and retired jobs?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if it is a temporary work service, like for people who cant find jobs, but can get work for weeks at a time, those jobs are considered to be "completed assignments" upon completion, so that might be why there are 2 categories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Job retirement is a normal procedure from the jobtracker to persist the jobs to disk and clear up memory. You can read more details on [the Cloudera blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/11/hadoop-log-location-and-retention/):

> Once a job is complete it is kept in memory (up to `mapred.jobtracker.completeuserjobs.maximum`) and on disk as per the above. There is a configuration value that controls the overall retirement policy of completed jobs:
>
> **Key**: `mapred.jobtracker.retirejob.interval`
>   **Default**: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000  (1 day)
>   In other words, completed jobs are retired after one day by default. The check for jobs to be retired is done by default every minute and can be controlled with:
>
> **Key**: `mapred.jobtracker.retirejob.check`
>   **Default**: 60 * 1000 (60s in msecs)
>   The check runs continually while the JobTracker is running. If a job is retired it is simply removed from the in-memory list of the JobTracker (it also removes all Tasks for the job etc.). Jobs are not retired under at least 1 minute (hardcoded in JobTracker.java) of their finish time. The retire call also removes the *JobTracker Local* (see above) file for the job. All that is left are the two files per retired job in the history directory (`hadoop.job.history.location`) plus – if enabled – the Per Job files (`hadoop.job.history.user.location`).